# Want to add index on run time generated columns or values

Tags: mysql

I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE `hashing` (
  `dctBinary` BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
  `mhbinary` BLOB NOT NULL,
)
```

and I write below query to get Hamming distance based on some condition:

```
SELECT 
    BIT_COUNT(BINARY '1011001101000110000101101100101010011110100110010111100000111001' ^ BINARY dctbinary ) AS hd1,
    BIT_COUNT(BINARY '101100111100100100110101101110110011011001100111110010010110010011011011000100111000000111011011011100101111110110001100100010010111000000100011100001111001101100011001101010110100001011101001001101111000001110011001100000111100111011001110010001100101110100011000101101110001100110111000101000110111000001011001111010101101010000010101001000101001100000111001011011110111100001110100001110101010010010000010010001011101000111011000000010111000100110011101000110011011110101001110100000100001011111001001011000111010000110000111111010010111110100000010100001110010011011000010' ^ BINARY mhbinary)/576 AS hd2 
    FROM Hashing HAVING hd1=0 OR hd2<=0.05 ORDER BY hd1 LIMIT 1;
```

it gives me result within 3 sec for 600 000 rows, but I want to get data within 1 sec for above 2 million rows

How to create index on hd1 and hd2 columns generated in above query? Are there any other options to improve the performance of the query

Comment: You cannot use an index for that, as you area applying an operation to a column. `hd1=0` should, if I understand your query correctly, be equal to `<yourfirstvalue> = dctbinary`, and for that you can use an index. I didn't count the number of bits in your second value (so I don't know how many bits are allowed to differ), but if it's e.g. 5, you can maybe split the value into 5 substrings (e.g. bit 1 to 100, 101 to 200 and so on). At least one of these has to be equal to the same portion of your compare string, and you can use an index for that again. Not sure if it will be faster in total.

Comment: this query works only in mysql 8.0

Comment: Was this a response to my comment or did you answer to an now deleted comment? If it is directed at me, I am not sure what you mean by that.